# Should we be able to put bounties on tag wikis?

Tags: feature-request, bounty, tag-wiki

I was wondering if offering a bounty to help create or improve a tag wiki has been considered before?

I had this idea after reviewing the [tag wiki for Polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/polymer/info). It definitely needs some attention. However it's been a while since I last used it and I'm sure there are people out there who are more up to date than I currently am. *(Ideally I'd like to target users who have a significant score in this tag.)*

Question: putting aside the technical intricacies of such a feature, do you think it would be useful to be able to put bounties on tag wikis?

---

EDIT - *Thanks all for your feedback so far* - Offering a bounty is just one way (though admittedly not the best way) to flag tag wiki that needs attention. Wether offering that capability would be useful or not, is essentially the question.

Perhaps just a little note similar to the one displayed when there is no tag wiki at all would be enough to start with?

In the context of Polymer, it could say: *"Some users have indicated that the tag wiki needs attention. Can you help improve it?"*

[image]

Comment: I think that's an interesting idea, if implemented properly it could definitely add to the site.

Comment: The technical intricacies are fairly important, as at present you can scarcely get any rep for tag wikis, and the review process is still barely able to weed out useless or wrong contributions, or outright copypasta. Adding a substantial rep incentive will require an even more substantial upgrade to ensure wiki review reliability.

Comment: My biggest concern is that when bounties are offered on questions, it draws fairly subpar answers. This would likely have the same, where people would be editing the tag wiki with copy+paste or otherwise bad edits; however, +1 cause I think it could still be worthwhile

Comment: Personally I think the whole bounty system as it stands should be scrapped. It isn't harmonized with the rest of the site. "Oh you made a lovely analogy in that answer - here, let me give you some user moderator privileges"...

Comment: I think the best way of attracting editors to tag wikis would be to attract *anyone* to them. Last I checked, they're completely unreachable on mobile, and hidden behind a bland "learn more" link on desktop; I bet a lot of users simply don't know they exist.

Comment: One huge avenue for abuse here is that tag wiki edits have to be approved by other users until 20,000 reputation. That means 99% of users (literally) could try for the bounty and potentially get declined if competing users review their edits and say "oh, no I wanna try for this". You could only get around that by making bounty edits non-reviewable, which opens *that* up for abuse ("oh, I can write some spam and earn 500 rep?! sweet!")

Comment: A tag with only one question should be removed instead of wasting efforts on its wiki.

Comment: I don't think that is a fair comment to make. Any tag whether popular or not has started with just one question. Frameworks, libraries and technology in general do evolve over time. Tags can be a static finite set.

Comment: The creator of the tag should do at least either, write a useful tag description or find matching questions to tag. If even the tag creator thinks it’s not worth the effort, then the tag most likely *is* not worth it.

Answer (score 24):

Tag wikis shouldn't be a popularity contest.

While bounties do attract more attention to whatever they're tied to, I'm not convinced it's the kind of attention tag wikis require.

It's also not possible to "vote" on the quality of an edit. There's no system in place where different versions can be compared, so I'm not sure how a bounty system *could* be implemented without re-writing how tag wiki edits work.

Comment: I didn't mean this as a popularity contest at all. Although I see what you're saying and I don't disagree with you. I do believe there's a gap though. There's a lot of efforts and energy to maintain the quality of questions and answers. I feel that somehow, the same energy and effort is sometimes needed for maintaining good relevant tag wiki content.

Comment: "Popularity contest" is a bit of a hyperbole: Adding a rep bonus to tag wiki edits would draw attention, but I'm not sure it's the right kind of attention.

Comment: *There's no system in place where different versions can be compared* Of course there is.  There is [wiki history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/250231/revisions) and [excerpt history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/250232/revisions).  Links to both can be found at the bottom of the tag wiki.

Comment: I mean different potential edits, @NathanOliver. Just like a question with multiple answers competing for the bounty.

Answer (score 7):

I like the idea of adding incentive for users to edit tag wikis. Offering a bounty on the edit itself would require some level of change in the background in order to vote on and award the bounty, which might take a while... One thought I had was why not use the normal Q/A format?

Q: The "phosphorjs" tag needs attention, please submit your proposed tag wiki edit below.

This would allow users to vote on which edit they think is best, with the winner being awarded the bounty and the edit being submitted (by the OP who has an investment in the tag). While this solution is not perfect since the edit is not automatically submitted/approved, there is no extra work that needs to be done by the devs. Now, where this type of question would fit into the community would be questionable. I would think it would be considered off-topic on the main site, but offering it on meta would not be as rewarding for the answers.

Down the line it might be a good idea to have the site itself noticing tags that need wiki edits and offering a bounty in this fashion, as opposed to users offering a bounty.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion. I like the idea of starting with a fairly "low tech" solution and see how it pans out. Thanks for this!

Comment: The only problem with this is that I think these types of questions would be off topic on the main site, so they would have to be posted on meta, where rep means nothing